# Save model as h5 / Save model as .ckpt

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, dataformat, style-transfer

i have had big troubles today with saving formats while training a style-transfer neural network.

The task is already solved  i feel, i only need to save my model and load it again. But i can't find a proper way to do it.

I used the following code from github to train a style-transfer network:

https://github.com/nikhilagrawal2000/Neural-Style-Transfer-with-Eager-Execution/blob/master/Neural_Style_Transfer_with_Eager_Execution.ipynb

I already succesfully trained the network.

Now, i saved the model using the following line:

```
model.save("/tmp/nst/test.h5")
```

For applying the saved neural network though, i need to use the network in a .ckpt format.

Can someone tell me how to switch the data formats between h5 and .ckpt ?

Or is there a specific save method for keras, so i can save it as .ckpt? 
(--> pseudocode: model.save_cpkt("/tmp/nst/test.ckpt")

Would be extremely happy if someone could explain that to me, i tried it for several hours now without success.

Comment: do you need checkpoint or tensorflow lite? there is a way to transform between tf.keras model and TfLite model

Answer (score 1):

You can save the weights in checkpoint format using:

```
model.save_weights("modelcheckpoint",save_format="tf")
```

You can read more about saving weights or models and chepoints [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#weights-only_saving_using_tensorflow_checkpoints)